# Slowing an object in a particular area using Farseer

Tags: c#, xna, farseer

I'm trying to set an area whereby if an object enters it, it becomes slowed down.

This is what i've got so far:-

```
        PhysicsBody = BodyFactory.CreateBody(World, new Vector2(x,y));
        PhysicsBody.BodyType = BodyType.Static;

        List<Vertices> vertList = EarclipDecomposer.ConvexPartition(verts);
        Fixtures = FixtureFactory.AttachCompoundPolygon(vertList, density, PhysicsBody);
```

What setting do I need for the area to cause a slow down to other objects - is it friction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post has several solutions for you.

http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/discussions/240883

You could use friction, drag coffecicients, LinearDamping, the VelocityLimietController or to just have two engines and switch between the two.